# Create web workers to process only few files at a time - javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-worker

I am using webworker concept to upload files.
If I select 10 files to upload, I am ending up creating 10 webworkers to process them.
I am thinking of creating 5 web worker threads to process the upload of 1st batch of five files, terminate the 5 threads 
and then pick up the next batch of 5 files to upload.
I am not sure how to achieve it.Please advise.

My current logic is:

```
for (var i = 0; i<files.length; i++){
    //create web worker 
    //upload the file
    //terminate the web worker
}
```

**EDIT:**

To achieve this I have tried to do something like this, but this goes on an infinite loop and never breaks. Please advise what is going wrong.

```
 var num = 5;
var alreadyPicked = new Set();
var pickList = [];
var isPicked = false;
while(true){
if( pickList.length == num ){
    $timeout( function() {}, 3000); //wait for 3 secs
}
for(var j=0; j<files.length; j++){
    isPicked = alreadyPicked.has( files[j] );
    if( !isPicked ){
        pickList.push( files[j] ); //add the file to the array if it is not processed
    }
    if( pickList.length === num ){
        break;
    }
}

if( pickList.length > 0 ){
    for( var j=0; j<pickList.length; j++ ){
        $scope.process( pickList[j] );
    }
}
else{
    break;
}
```

`}`

```
$scope.process = function(item){
    //rest api call to upload the file to server
    if( success || error ){
        pickList.splice( pickList.indexOf(item,1));
        alreadyPicked.add(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

An Idea:

1. Create an Array before, listing all your files.
2. Grab 5 items of this array for the loop.
3. When a worker is finished remove this filename from the array
4. Grab another 5 items from your Array, and repeat.